# referencing another project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, reference, ide, package

1. I created project A with package name "A"
2. I created another project called "B"
3. Properties->Java Build Path->Modulepath
   added "A"
4. project B has a source file with "import A" statement

I get "The package A is not accessible"

Comment: what is the proper way to add a project and reference it?     i am new to eclipse and coming from C# if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You have the package or the project A stored into another folder.
Option 2: You've deleted A or any content related with A so it's not there anymore

Comment: of course I have a project A in a different folder.  it seems natural to put it in a different folder than subfolder of project B since it is a library.   What is right way of going about it in java?

Answer (score 0):

That you have added the project to the modulepath and not to the classpath means that you are using [Java Platform Module System (**JPMS**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System): each of the two projects contains the file **`module-info.java` in the default package**.

You have two options:

- In the `module-info.java` files do the following:

  - Project A must export the packages that you want to use in project B:
    In `module-info.java` of project A add for each exported package a line
    **`exports <package-to-export>;`**
  - In project B the dependency to the module of project A must be defined:
    In `module-info.java` of project A add the line
    **`requires <project-A-module-name>;`**
- **Delete both `module-info.java` files** (in most cases this is the recommended solution)